# SQL IN function and select not match criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using a SQL IN clause to get student scores for a given grade e.g. 1,2,3,4 in Reading. A student may not receive any scores that have 4. Is there a way to select a not matched condition IN SQL clause

Here is the query

```
select
score, 
count(*) as [countTimes]
from ScoresTable
where  score IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Score

If a student has never received a 4, I need to create a row like 4,0
example resultset

```
Score Count
1       2
2       3
3       1
4       0
```

the current query is using an IN clause. If there are no records that match IN clause, the row is not diislayed

```
Score Count
1       2
2       3
3       1
4       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a `left join`:

```
select v.score, count(s.score) as [countTimes]
from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)
     ) v(score) left join
     ScoresTable s
     on s.score = v.score
group by v.score;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a table with the available score values just 'build' one, and redo yout query like this (updated after @Serg comment)

```
select
    S.score, 
    count(ST.Score) as [countTimes]
from 
(   Select 1 as Score 
    union all
    Select 2 as Score 
    union all
    Select 3 as Score 
    union all
    Select 4 as Score ) as S 
left join 
    ScoresTable ST on S.Score = ST.Score
GROUP BY 
    S.score
ORDER BY 
    S.score
```

Comment: `count(*)` will never return 0.

Comment: This will only work if there is atleast 1 entry in ScoresTable for each score. However, we have a scenario where a student may never receive a 4. In that scenario, there will not be any entry in ScoresTable and no rows will be returned for 4.

Comment: You are mistaken. That's why we are doing a left join. This will ensure that all values from 1 to 4 will be displayed, regardless of the records existing on the ScoresTable. Even if the ScoreTable had no records, all score values will be displayed and all, will have a count of 0.

Comment: Thanks! I was using WHERE in outer join and that was causing the issue. To retrieve the result set, I'd to use ON

Answer (score 0):

Left join the list of scores  and `ScoresTable`

```
select
 sl.score, 
 count(st.score) as [countTimes]
from (
   values (1),(2),(3),(4)
 ) sl (score)
left join ScoresTable st on st.score = sl.score
group by sl.score
```